# PHP SoapClient - "failed to load external entity" although WSDL is valid and accessable in browser/curl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

This issue has been plaguing me for a few hours. I can access the wsdl perfectly fine in my browser and using curl, however PHP SoapClient returns an error when using the following code:

```
$ps_client = new SoapClient("https://ppds.hitpromo.net/productData");
```

Here is the error it's returning:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: 
[WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ppds.hitpromo.net/productData' : 
failed to load external entity "https://ppds.hitpromo.net/productData"
```

I tried a variety of solutions including setting various options when calling the constructor but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score -2):

This ended up not being the actual fix, it was happening because SSL was not enabled in php. I fixed it by commenting out this line in php.ini:

```
extension=openssl
```

In my case, I was able to construct the SoapClient using the http uri, however it threw an error when calling functions because SSL was not enabled.

**OLD ANSWER:**
Turns out this was a really simple fix. I'm not sure why, but changing it from https to http fixed everything:

```
$ps_client = new SoapClient("http://ppds.hitpromo.net/productData");
```

Really frustrating issue, because I've been playing around with this same WSDL on java and did not run into this while using ksoap. I wanted to post it because I'm sure someone might have the same problem some day.

Answer (score -2):

This error occurs because your site is on a host whose firewall prevents swaps.
Contact your host company to add the IP of the swap site to the firewall whitelist.
You do not need to delete ssl or coding to ignore it.